# Change URL in email sent by SSRS

Tags: email, iis, reporting-services, subscription, ssrs-2012

I have a reportserver that is succesfully able to send out subscriptions as emails.
However, if I include the link to the report, the link is 'local'.
The reportserver can be reached using

- http://reporting.mycompany.com
  OR internally through our VPN.

The link in the email added by SSRS looks like

```
 - http://HOST_NAME/ReportServer/PATH_TO_REPORT
```

I have looked, tried, searched but I cannot find  as solution.
In the RS Configuration Manager two URL's have been added for the Web Service URL:

```
 - http://reporting.mycompany.com:80/ReportServer
 - http://HOST_NAME:80/ReportServer.
```

If I remove the second I can no longer connect, internally OR externally.

The Report Manager URL is set up as

```
 - http://reporting.mycompany.com:80/Reports
```

The only thing I want is to have the URL in the emails to look like

```
 - http://reporting.mycompany.com:80/ReportServer/PATH_TO_REPORT
```

I have been looking at the RS Configuration Manager, the RSconfig file, IIS but for the love of me, I cannot find a way to change the link in the email......

Who can point me in the right direction?
Thanks for thinking with me!

Instructions on [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic673108-162-1.aspx)  didn't help either :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions in ***this link*** are correct;
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic673108-162-1.aspx
The fault actually was in the certificate that was being used.....

Answer (score 2):

The link also worked for me but I had to use ReportServer instead of Reports in the

```
Correct url: "http://myserver.mydomain.com/ReportServer
                                                 ^
Incorrect url: "http://myserver.mydomain.com/Reports
                                                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The location on SSRS 2019 is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config
Look for `<UrlRoot>` and enter `http://<youralias>/ReportServer`